# Count similar objects by incrementing number of rows

Tags: r

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` as follows.

```
df1 

    user
1    U1
2    U2
3    U3
4    U4
5    U5
6    U6
7    U7
8    U8
9    U9
10   U10



 df2
     user
1   U3
2   U4
3   U10
```

I want to check how many users from `df2` are available in `df1` when I take first 2 rows together, first 4 rows together, etc.

What I am expecting is;

```
 selected_users   matching_users
    2              0
    4              2
    6              2
    8              2 
   10              3
```

In my real data df1 has 1000 rows and I may increment 50 rows at a time.

I was using a tedious way which takes each step manually using head(df1,2), head(df1,4) etc. But I feel there should be a much easier way to do this.

Could someone suggest a efficient way pls.

Comment: And what is the pattern for the "steps"? Are you just incrementing the number of rows in `df1` by 2? And do you want to just count how many there are? or you want to actually know which "users" from df2 are in df1?

Comment: yes, in the example increment by 2, but in my real case I might increment by 50

Comment: that is the number of users selected from df1 (simply the increment by 2 )

Comment: I've edited my answer to take into account your changes

Comment: Are df1$user and df2$user categorical or character?

Comment: @user31264 Don't think it matters in this case. `%in%` can handle factor variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for lapply, sapply, or auxillary functions.

```
df1 = data.frame(user = c("U1", "U2", "U3", "U4", "U5",
    "U6", "U7", "U8", "U9", "U10"))
df2 = data.frame(user = c("U3", "U4", "U10"))
a=cumsum(df1$user %in% df2$user)
ind=seq(2,10,2)
cbind(ind,a[ind])
```

Output:

```
     ind  
[1,]   2 0
[2,]   4 2
[3,]   6 2
[4,]   8 2
[5,]  10 3
```

Comment: I agree that this is a more efficient answer, but I initially thought OP might also want to know which users were matched at each increment

Comment: I really appreciate both of your answers @userR and user31264 , and saved my time a lot

Answer (score 3):

#### This answer returns a list of matches for each increment

```
df1 = data.frame(user = c("U1", "U2", "U3", "U4", "U5", "U6", "U7", "U8", "U9", "U10"))
df2 = data.frame(user = c("U3", "U4", "U10"))

count_incre = function(DF1, DF2, increments){
  return(DF2[DF2$user %in% head(DF1, increments)$user,])
}

lapply(seq(2, nrow(df1), 2), function(x) count_incre(df1, df2, x))

# [[1]]
# factor(0)
# Levels: U10 U3 U4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] U3 U4
# Levels: U10 U3 U4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] U3 U4
# Levels: U10 U3 U4
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] U3 U4
# Levels: U10 U3 U4
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] U3  U4  U10
# Levels: U10 U3 U4
```

I first created a function `count_incre` that takes `df1`, `df2`, and the number of rows for `head()` and returns all "users" from `DF2` that can be found in `head(DF1, increments)`. Then applied that function over a vector of `increments` which I specified as `seq(2, nrow(df1), 2)` (basically all even numbers) using `lapply`. You can modify `seq(2, nrow(df1), 2)` to specify any sequence you want.

#### To only count the number of matches

```
increments = seq(2, nrow(df1), 2)
matching_users = sapply(increments, function(x) length(count_incre(df1, df2, x)))

# [1] 0 2 2 2 3

data.frame(selected_users = increments, matching_users)

#   selected_users matching_users
# 1              2              0
# 2              4              2
# 3              6              2
# 4              8              2
# 5             10              3
```

This returns a vector of *number of matches* for each increment

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- data.frame(user = paste0("U",seq(1,1000)))
df2 <- data.frame(user = paste0("U",sample(seq(1,2000),1000,replace = F)))
head(df1)
  user
1   U1
2   U2
3   U3
4   U4
5   U5
6   U6
head(df2)
   user
1  U537
2 U1133
3  U769
4  U217
5 U1924
6  U536
```

I use **intersect** to calculate the match number.

```
find_match <- function (df1, df2, step){
  result <- data.frame(selected_users = rep(0, nrow(df1) / step),matching_users = rep(0, nrow(df1) / step))
  time <- 1
  increment_vec <- seq(step, nrow(df1), by=step)
  for(i in increment_vec){
    result[time,1] <- i
    result[time,2] <- length(intersect(unlist(df1), unlist(df2[1:i, 1])))
    time <- time + 1
  }
  return(result)
}
find_match(df1,df2,step=50)
```

And the result is :

```
   selected_users matching_users
1              50             26
2             100             47
3             150             73
4             200             99
5             250            130
6             300            151
7             350            172
8             400            199
9             450            225
10            500            248
11            550            273
12            600            298
13            650            321
14            700            348
15            750            372
16            800            398
17            850            429
18            900            453
19            950            472
20           1000            499
```